# Out of memory exception with BeginRead

Tags: c#, object, tcpclient, networkstream, binaryformatter

The idea behind this small project is developing a chat application with a difference that I want to send objects instead of just plain strings. So far, this is what I have.

If I deserialize on the constructor, it works just fine (UserDTO only has 2 string fields for now), however, I plan on having multiple clients sending data to the server anytime they wish. I'm having some difficulty understanding how it works and how to fix the error (like this, it gives an "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown." at the Deseralize line) even after reading MS's documentation and I'd like some ideas from you guys.

Note to whoever tries to compile this: Binaryformatter has a way of doing this as in: Let's say UserDTO has properties string Name, string Email
Applying this class to a client and the server, you must build it using a class library and add reference of this to both projects, because somehow binaryformater says that even tho if you create the same class in both projects, deserializing claims it cannot map the object. I'll be leaving a sample of the client that I am using below.

Server:

```
class Program {
const int serverPort = 60967;
static List<UserConnection> clientList = new List<UserConnection>();
static TcpListener listener;
static Thread listenerThread;


static void Main(string[] args) {
        listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoListen));
        listenerThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server Started");
        //while (true) {
            string a = Console.ReadLine()
        //}
   }

static void DoListen() {
        try {
            listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, serverPort);
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening [...]");
            do {
                UserConnection client = new UserConnection(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
                //clientList.Add(client);
                Console.WriteLine("New connection found"); 
            } while (true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}



public class UserConnection {
private TcpClient clientInfo;
private byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2000];
const int READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;

public UserConnection(TcpClient client) {
    clientInfo = client;
    clientInfo.GetStream().BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, READ_BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(StreamReceiver), null);
}

private void StreamReceiver(IAsyncResult ar) {
    try
    {
        if (client.GetStream().CanRead) {
        lock (clientInfo.GetStream()) {
            var strm = clientInfo.GetStream();
            int BytesRead = clientInfo.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var mydat = (UserDTO)formatter.Deserialize(strm);
        }
        lock (clientInfo.GetStream()) {
            clientInfo.GetStream().BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, READ_BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(StreamReceiver), null);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
            ConnectResult("localhost", 60967);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static string ConnectResult(string ip, int port) {
        try {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
            AttemptLogin(client);
            return "Connection Succeeded";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return "Server is not active.  Please start server and try again.      " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    static void AttemptLogin(TcpClient client) {
        UserDTO obj = new UserDTO("email", "username");
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var stream = client.GetStream(); 
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent Object");
    }
}
```

Comment: When does the `while (true);` loop exit? (Answer: when the program runs out of memory I assume)

Comment: Just for testing purposes, it never exits for now, it's mainly the deserializing part that is giving me a hard time (when working with string and streamwriter it works just fine with multiple clients)

Comment: @Quantic I doubt that's the problem as the loop isn't increasing the amount of memory that's being used.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Are you sure? I just got OOM exception doing this: `var test = new List<string>(); while (true) { test.Add(null); }`, so even if `client` is null this line should be increasing memory: `clientList.Add(client);`

Comment: He only proceeds to insert into the list after he accepts a TCPConnection (AcceptTcpClient()), untill then he just awaits for a connection to arrive (as far as I tested)

Comment: @Quantic does have a good point about you adding clients but never removing them - that does appear to be a memory leak. (I don't think the "while (true) string a = Console.ReadLine()" line is itself causing the problem though). I'm not positive that that particular memory leak is what's causing your issue but it's definitely worth fixing either way.

Comment: Just removed that line, the problem stands tho (this is mainly the begining of the project so ence the not removing client part - thanks for the heads up)     the  Edit: change in code -> "string a = Console.ReadLine()"  is just so the main thread stands still

Comment: I'm not sure that completely removing that line is the solution, just as long as there's some way to remove the client from the list once they're disconnected (otherwise there'll be a memory leak). The first while loop that's just getting user input isn't a problem since it can't cause an out of memory exception - the string variable you're creating inside the loop becomes eligible for garbage collection right away.

Comment: @Quantic I might have misread your statement, were you referring to the "while (true) string a = Console.ReadLine()" loop or the loop where he was adding the clients? (Reading your second comment I assume you meant the second one, which you correctly point out *is*, in fact, a memory leak since there's no way to remove clients - I thought you meant the first loop at first, which obviously isn't increasing memory).

Comment: You have a stream and read it into a byte[], but then you pass the read stream into the deserialize method. Why not either leave your stream alone and use it at position 0 instead of reading and moving its position or just read all bytes and then use your byte[] and pass that into the Deserialize? I am guessing your stream position is at the end (there is nothing more for it read).

Comment: @TyCobb how would the implementation resemble? I'm having a hard time understanding the concept

Comment: I've rolled back the question. If you have a new question, feel free to create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing all of the `BeginRead()` calls, try just taking the stream and passing it into the `BinaryFormatter.DeSerialize()` method.

```
public UserConnection(TcpClient client) {
    clientInfo = client;
    //clientInfo.GetStream().BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, READ_BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(StreamReceiver), null);
    var strm = clientInfo.GetStream();
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var mydat = (UserDTO)formatter.Deserialize(strm);
}
```

My guess is that your stream position is already moved, if not at the end. When you pass it into the `Deserialize()`, there just isn't anymore data for it to read. In fact, your `byte[] readBuffer` probably has all of the data you wanted if your DTO can't hold more than 2000 bytes. If this is the case, then you should be able to use the bytes in `readBuffer` to deserialize instead.

Comment: Well, that does work like I wrote above, however the question would become: How can a user send data in a async way, because that will only execute once

Comment: In that scenario then, you end up using the `byte[]` you have. That's where all your data is stored. You can't use `GetStream()` because it has already been read. `readBuffer` contains your data and you have to do checks to know if it has all of the data to actually be `UserDTO` or if you only have some of the data. The gist, is don't use the stream for Deserialize. Use the bytes you already have to create the object. You may want to look into BitConverter or BinaryReader instead if your object can contain more than 2000 bytes because if it does, you need to know when a UserDTO starts/ends.

Comment: thank you for the help, I updated the question because it's giving me a weird error atm, what do you think is happening?

Comment: @abr Feel free to create a new question.